# video.audioTracks is not working as expected for large video

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-video

From [MDN Web Platform Experimental Features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks), It seems that it is possible to control a dual audio video's Audio Track Selection using javascript by enabling the flag. I enabled the chrome flag option and then tested with a 720p dual audio 20 minutes video. when I execute `video.audioTracks`, I see 2 audio tracks. But After that, If I try with a 2 hour 720p dual audio video, sometimes I see only 1 audio track and sometimes 0 audio tracks. What's the problem here? Is there any problem with the video meta data or video's file size or video encoding? I'm sure that both of the video are dual audio. Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u9f2x5wj/

And Here are Some Images:
[image: 20 min vid]
[image: 2 hour vid]

Comment: The last time I checked neither Chrome nor Firefox implement loading an `.mkv` file directy. You'll have to create a `Blob` of the media and change to `"video/webm"` for the media to play in an `HTMLVideoElement`.

Comment: Are you sure those URL's are correct?

Comment: Yes, Chrome supports MKV Video's now. So it is all right!

Comment: Neither resource is served with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header. Try with this URL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/native-messaging-mkvmerge/master/native-messaging-mkvmerge-vp8.webm

Comment: I didn’t mean that. The resource is ok. It loads perfectly, you can open the fiddle and check it by yourself (Make sure the specified flag is enabled). The problem is about audioTracks. Lower length video works perfectly with the option but larger video does not.

Comment: I'm on Chromium 125, which does not support MP4. The MKV file never loads, throws a network error: `TypeError: Failed to fetch`. What codecs does the MKV file contain for video and audio? Do you have other URL's to test?

Comment: I don’t know the codec exactly. Yes, I have other URL but they are also same mkv and mp4 files. I'm on Google Chrome 122.0.6261.129 and it support both mp4 and mkv

Comment: What happens when you use the URL I linked to above that is served with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` header?

Comment: It plays normally. Nothing special here. It shows 1 audio stream. And as far as I know, that CORS header is only required when the video tag has crossorigin=anonymous attribute. Since I didn’t added that attribute, there's nothing special noticed.

Comment: The audio track length is greater than 0. What is the use case for accessing the `audioTracks`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257240/discussion-between-s-m-shahriar-zarir-and-guest271314).

Comment: @SMShahriarZarir Your MP4 has its metadata at the back of the file. To fix: It will work smoother if you edit a copy to have the metadata (called `moov` data) at the front. This way, the metadata loads first and can correctly report the number of tracks (without doing a 1 gig download just to reach same metadata at back, which is your current state). PS: You can use a tool like FFMpeg to fix the metadata. Research `ffmpeg mp4 fast start` in your Google searching.

Comment: @VC.One Thanks for the hint. I understand what you said. But I'm seeing 2/3 items of Data Stream (bin_data) when I run `ffmpeg -i video.mp4`. Is that normal?

Comment: @VC.One I tried to do what you said by adding `-movflags +faststart` to my command. But it seems it didn’t worked. Basically, I'm converting MKV to MP4. when I play the mkv file, chrome shows dual audio. But when I play the converted mp4 video, it shows single audio. And I noticed one more thing (which I told in the last comment) that the MKV file has single Data Stream according to ffmpeg. But the converted MP4 gets 2 Data Stream. If I convert the MP4 to MP4 (means doing nothing), the output video gets one additional Data Stream.